# Why loading from http return different value then loading from https for same content?

Tags: javascript, http, web, server, https

I have modified script to get dictionary meaning for Chinese characters.

In following in `loadDictData()` method when localhost used to get dictionary data file then the `search` return correct result but when cdn used to get dictionary data file then the `search` method return different result.

This is result for all files loaded from localhost.

```
git clone https://github.com/cschiller/zhongwen.git
cd zhongwen
python -m http.server
```

Then open browser and paste below script the result will be similar.

[image]

This is result for dictionary data cedict_ts.u8 loaded from cdn. Open new tab with cdn url, then paste below script in dev console. The result is different.

[image]

```js
let host = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

async function loadDictData() {
    let wordIndex = fetch(`${host}/data/cedict.idx`).then(r => r.text());
    let grammarKeywords = fetch(`${host}/data/grammarKeywordsMin.json`).then(r => r.json());
    let vocabKeywords = fetch(`${host}/data/vocabularyKeywordsMin.json`).then(r => r.json());

    // comment and uncomment to test the result
    host = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cschiller/zhongwen@latest";

    let wordDict = fetch(`${host}/data/cedict_ts.u8`).then(r => r.text());

    return Promise.all([wordDict, wordIndex, grammarKeywords, vocabKeywords]);
}

class ZhongwenDictionary {

    constructor(wordDict, wordIndex, grammarKeywords, vocabKeywords) {
        this.wordDict = wordDict;
        this.wordIndex = wordIndex;
        this.grammarKeywords = grammarKeywords;
        this.vocabKeywords = vocabKeywords;
        this.cache = {};
    }

    static find(needle, haystack) {

        let beg = 0;
        let end = haystack.length - 1;

        while (beg < end) {
            let mi = Math.floor((beg + end) / 2);
            let i = haystack.lastIndexOf('\n', mi) + 1;

            let mis = haystack.substr(i, needle.length);
            if (needle < mis) {
                end = i - 1;
            } else if (needle > mis) {
                beg = haystack.indexOf('\n', mi + 1) + 1;
            } else {
                return haystack.substring(i, haystack.indexOf('\n', mi + 1));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    hasGrammarKeyword(keyword) {
        return this.grammarKeywords[keyword];
    }

    hasVocabKeyword(keyword) {
        return this.vocabKeywords[keyword];
    }

    wordSearch(word, max) {

        let entry = { data: [] };

        let dict = this.wordDict;
        let index = this.wordIndex;

        let maxTrim = max || 7;

        let count = 0;
        let maxLen = 0;

        WHILE:
        while (word.length > 0) {

            let ix = this.cache[word];
            if (!ix) {
                ix = ZhongwenDictionary.find(word + ',', index);
                if (!ix) {
                    this.cache[word] = [];
                    continue;
                }
                ix = ix.split(',');
                this.cache[word] = ix;
            }

            for (let j = 1; j < ix.length; ++j) {
                let offset = ix[j];

                let dentry = dict.substring(offset, dict.indexOf('\n', offset));

                if (count >= maxTrim) {
                    entry.more = 1;
                    break WHILE;
                }

                ++count;
                if (maxLen === 0) {
                    maxLen = word.length;
                }

                entry.data.push([dentry, word]);
            }

            word = word.substr(0, word.length - 1);
        }

        if (entry.data.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        entry.matchLen = maxLen;
        return entry;
    }
}

async function loadDictionary() {
    const [wordDict, wordIndex, grammarKeywords, vocabKeywords] = await loadDictData();
    return new ZhongwenDictionary(wordDict, wordIndex, grammarKeywords, vocabKeywords);
}

let dict;
await loadDictionary().then(r => dict = r);

function search(text) {

    if (!dict) {
        return;
    }

    let entry = dict.wordSearch(text);

    console.log("entry", entry);

    if (entry) {
        for (let i = 0; i < entry.data.length; i++) {
            let word = entry.data[i][1];
            if (dict.hasGrammarKeyword(word) && (entry.matchLen === word.length)) {
                // the final index should be the last one with the maximum length
                entry.grammar = { keyword: word, index: i };
            }
            if (dict.hasVocabKeyword(word) && (entry.matchLen === word.length)) {
                // the final index should be the last one with the maximum length
                entry.vocab = { keyword: word, index: i };
            }
        }
    }

    return entry;
}

let res = search("你好");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used gzip to compress the dictionary file then uncompress using `DecompressionStream` in browser. The result is same now.

```js
const decompress = async (url) => {
  const ds = new DecompressionStream('gzip');
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const blob_in = await response.blob();
  const stream_in = blob_in.stream().pipeThrough(ds);
  const blob_out = await new Response(stream_in).blob();
  return await blob_out.text();
};

let wordDict = await decompress('http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/cedict_ts.u8.gz');
```